# How do unit tests go into the full program?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, testing

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm not sure how to phrase it, which is probably why I can't find an answer.
When someone uses unit tests, how does that go into the full program?
Say a unit test is written and goes through the testing process, then what happens?
I assume it's not a simple copy and paste between 2 projects.
I'm asking generally and not about a specific language.

I tried searching for Test-Driven Development, workflows, integration testing, continuous integration, among other keywords but it's not exactly what I have in mind.
TIA

For example, my primary interest is C++ at the moment and I like to use VS Code. I don’t understand how you make the final program after you make the tests. How do you transfer those tests to the main project?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, unit testing happens concurrently to the program.

Comment: Say for example you're making a calculator. Do you have a project for the calculator, and another project for the unit tests for the calculator? And when you've tested a function, is it just a copy and paste from the unit test to the main project?

Comment: I suppose that would depend on what language and testing framework you are using. I would think that they should be together. Copy-pasting is a bad idea because you have to manually keep two copies in sync; test the production code. Maybe if we could have more details about this specific case?

Comment: My primary interest is C++ at the moment. So Google test, boost.test, and cppunit come to mind. I also like to use VS Code. I don't understand how you go from the unit tests to the full program. I'll edit my question as well

Comment: Much better. A minimal sample calculator on with you want to perform one test would allow answers to be specific. I haven't used VS Code, but I'm sure many people have the same problem getting started. I would also tag C++ and VS Code, since you are probably asking about that implementation specifically.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to present my question. I'm new to the site

Comment: A simple approach is compile everything except your main function into a static library and then both your "real" program and the unit test can link to the static library to do their bits

Comment: Just to clarify, the unit tests are not part of the program that you ship to customers. The unit tests are in essence one or more separate programs designed to test the library code. If you use a testing framework the test program will typically be provided by the framework and the tests will then reside in test libraries - still not shipped with the product.

Comment: @doron Your answer is the closest to understanding what I'm trying to ask. That's a good idea as well